# WPF DataGrid grouping datas

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here's an article I found on the web to hroupe datas in a WPF Datagrid :
[Grouping in DataGrid in WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/)

I want to test it in a WPF application with data coming from an Entity Framework `DataContext`.
First I want to check that data are correctly implemented in the `DataGrid`.
But the `DataGrid` stays empty.
Here's may *xaml* :

```html
<UserControl x:Class="GESTION_CONGELATION_V2.User_Controls.ViewPvi_UC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Pvi_DT">
        
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

My *.cs*

```
public partial class ViewPvi_UC : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<VW_PVI_2> pvi = new ObservableCollection<VW_PVI_2>();
    public ViewPvi_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<VW_PVI_2> pvi = new ObservableCollection<VW_PVI_2>();
        Pvi_DT.ItemsSource = pvi;
    }
}
```

and my Entity Framework class

```
public partial class VW_PVI_2
{
    public int PVI_ID { get; set; }
    public string VE_NOM { get; set; }
    public string VD_VIRTUAL { get; set; }
    public string VE_OLD_NAME { get; set; }
    public string ST_LIB { get; set; }
    public string VE_COMM { get; set; }
    public string IMP_NOM { get; set; }
    public string IMP_IP { get; set; }
    public string IMP_MAC { get; set; }
    public string ST_LIB_IMP { get; set; }
    public string IMP_COMM { get; set; }
    public string SERV_NOM { get; set; }
    public string PO_NOM { get; set; }
}
```

and the result in the datagrid
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your the `pvi` declaration as following, to use the `ICollectionView`:

```cs
public partial class ViewPvi_UC : UserControl
{
    public ICollectionView pvi { get; set; }
    public ViewPvi_UC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
    }

    async private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task<object>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Select all `VW_PVI_2` from your table here to be populate the `pvi`
            IList<VW_PVI_2> data= YourDbContext.YourTable.Select(r => r).ToList();
            pvi = new ObservableCollection<VW_PVI_2>(data);
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {  Pvi_DT.ItemsSource = pvi; });
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        });
    }
}
```

Adding the `Loaded` event in the XAML:

```
<UserControl ...
    d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <DataGrid x:Name="Pvi_DT">
        
    </DataGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Loading the data from a table is moved to the `Loaded` event handler and performing asynchronously. Because of loading data can take some time. Therefore is is possible to implement some logic to show a message that loading data is performing to indicate the user about this process.

In case you want to hide some columns (for example `PVI_ID`) it is possible to use a custom attribute:

```
public class HiddenAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public partial class VW_PVI_2
{
    [Hidden]
    public int PVI_ID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then add the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler declaration to the `dataGrid` to the XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" AutoGeneratingColumn="Pvi_DT_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

And the handler declaration to hide some columns:

```
private void Pvi_DT_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyDescriptor is PropertyDescriptor prop && prop.Attributes.OfType<HiddenAttribute>().Any())
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. just one thing, i don't know what to write after :  IList<VW_PVI_2> data= ?? is it a select * from my table ?

Comment: @Jean François Collombet: Exactly. It should any _LINQ ti Entities_ select query like: `YourDbContext.YourTable.Select(row => row).ToList();` Look at the tutorial: [Linq-to-Entities Query](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx) or [Execute Raw SQL Queries in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx). Any further questions related to your post is welcome!